# Default namespace with FOR XML PATH

Tags: xml, t-sql, for-xml-path

Consider the following SQL:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.mynamespace.co.uk')
,CTE_DummyData AS (
    select id=1
)
select TOP 1
    [@ID]=1,
    (select top 1 [@ID] = 1 FROM CTE_DummyData FOR XML PATH ('Child'), TYPE)
from CTE_DummyData
FOR XML PATH ('Parent')
```

Thie returns the xml:

```
<Parent xmlns="http://www.mynamespace.co.uk" ID="1">
  <Child xmlns="http://www.mynamespace.co.uk" ID="1" />
</Parent>
```

What I need is to return the xml with the xmlns declaration on only the root element. eg:

```
<Parent xmlns="http://www.mynamespace.co.uk" ID="1">
  <Child ID="1" />
</Parent>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Note: 
The above SQL is an extreme simplification of the actual code, which produces a complex document, so changing from FOR XML PATH isn't really an option without giving me a couple of days of extra work to do. To be clear on the the top level of the entire document is required to have the NS, and all children should be without.

Comment: I can't find a way, but they should have the same meaning - why can't you use the first form?

Comment: @Damien: This is part of a data migration process. While the first document means the same (as you say) it doesn't work when we pass it into the (third party) import web service. I think the issue is that its using the sub-queries. If you use a single query, and define the Child element using `[Child/@ID]` it works ok, but that would require a bit of a rethink on the code (which I've inherited)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ["query from hell"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345137%28v=sql.90%29.aspx#forxml2k5_topic7)

```
;with CTE_DummyData AS (
    select id=1
)
select 1 as tag,
       0 as parent,
       'http://www.mynamespace.co.uk' as [Parent!1!xmlns],
       id as [Parent!1!ID],
       null as [Child!2!ID]
from CTE_DummyData       
union all
select top 1
       2,
       1,
       null,
       null,
       id
from CTE_DummyData       
for xml explicit
```

Comment: +1 aargh - that would be terrible to try and implement in my real situation! The idea is good though and I've got a way of working using this to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a UDF to generate child nodes. E.g.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_get_child_section] (
    @serviceHeaderId INT
 )
RETURNS XML

BEGIN

    DECLARE @result XML;

    SELECT @result = 
    (
        SELECT 1 AS 'ChildElement'
        FOR XML PATH('Child')
    )

    RETURN @result

END


GO

DECLARE @Ids TABLE
( 
    ID int 
)

INSERT INTO @Ids
SELECT 1 AS ID 
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS ID

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www...com/content')
SELECT 
    [dbo].[udf_get_child_section](ID)
FROM 
    @Ids
FOR XML PATH('Parent')
```

Comment: The original thing was though that this was a simplification, of a more complex document, so the idea is that only the top level element shows the NS, and all children (at all levels) don't have it. You solution would be excellent if it could be turned around so that the top level element is produced by the UDF, and the rest not. Do you think you can work it that way?