# Write specifically structured XML from t-sql query

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, bcp

I would like to be able to write out an XML file in this specific format. I've been reading up on `bcp` and experimenting with `FOR XML` but can't seem to achieve what I need here. I would appreciate any help in the right direction. While I know I could refactor the code that would consume this XML output; I'd like to be adventurous here and stick to the task at hand without changing anything.

SQL code for recreating a temp var table dataset

```
declare @dataset table(Color nvarchar(10), Number int, Code nvarchar(10))

insert into @dataset 
  select 'Green', 12345, 'US1'
  union
  select 'Red', 56789, 'US2'

select * from @dataset
```

And from this query I would like to generate the following XML document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<test>
  <collection>
    <Case>
      <input>
        <attribute name="Color">Green</attribute>
        <attribute name="Number">12345</attribute>
        <attribute name="Code">US1</attribute>
      </input>
    </Case>
    <Case>
      <input>
        <attribute name="Color">Red</attribute>
        <attribute name="Number">56789</attribute>
        <attribute name="Code">US2</attribute>
      </input>
    </Case>
  </collection>
</test>
```

I will defer to you experts to tell me if this is too ridiculous to be accomplished, but I think it "is" possible as I've got a little close so far.

I've been tinkering with this and able to write out XML files.

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "Query Here" queryout "c:\filename.xml" -c -T'
```

Thanks SO members!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
select (
       select (
              select 'Color' as [attribute/@name],
                     Color as [attribute],
                     null,
                     'Number' as [attribute/@name],
                     Number as [attribute],
                     null,
                     'Code' as [attribute/@name],
                     Code as [attribute]
              for xml path('input'), type 
              ) 
       from @dataset
       for xml path('Case'), root('collection'), type
       )
for xml path('test'), type
```

Comment: didn't know the null trick to mix attributes and elements with same names, brilliant!

Comment: Simple and effective! I was thinking of using FOR XML EXPLICIT but this looks much cleaner.

Comment: @SAS ugh. Luckily there is so far only one case I have seen where you need to use [for xml explicit.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751631/default-namespace-with-for-xml-path)

Comment: @MikaelEriksson You sir are THE MAN! :) Thanks for a quick and elegant solution.  I knew that SO would have the answer.